# standalone package resize as in original document

Tags: standalone, png, resize

I am trying to use Latex images on my website. For this I use the standalone package. The problem is that it generates too large images. The text on these is much larger than the normal text on my website. (preview of html file on the screenshot below)
[image]

Can I somehow make it look like in a book, see screenshot?[image]

Code for generating this png file is following:

```
\documentclass[preview, 12pt, a4paper, obeyclassoptions=true, dvipsnames,svgnames,convert={outext=.png, size=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\chaptermark}{

}

\newcommand{\mypair}[2]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix} #1\\ #2\end{bmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\mymatrix}[4]{\ensuremath{\begin{bmatrix} #1 & #2\\ #3 & #4\end{bmatrix}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{mypic}
  {\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[mys]}
  {\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}}

\tikzstyle{mys}=[row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,line width=.5mm]

\begin{document}\begin{figure}
[ht] \tikzstyle{q}=[rectangle, draw=none, inner sep=1mm] \tikzstyle{l}=[rectangle, draw=none, fill=white, inner sep=1mm]

    \begin{mypic}{1}{.9}
        \begin{scope}
        [yscale=.9]\tikzstyle{q}=[rectangle,draw] \node (3) at (4,6) {$1 \le x \le 7$}; \node[q] (2) at (4,5) {$x=4$?}; \node (d1) at (4,3.5) {Yes!}; \node (l2) at (2,3.5) {$1 \le x \le 3$}; \node (l3) at (6,3.5) {$5 \le x \le 7$}; \draw (2) -- (2,5); \draw[->] (2,5) -- node[l] {$x<4$} (l2); \draw (2) -- (6,5); \draw[->] (6,5) -- node[l] {$x>4$} (l3); \draw[->] (3) -- (2); \draw[->] (2) -- (d1); \node[q] (a) at (2,2.5) {$x=2$?}; \node[q] (b) at (6,2.5) {$x=6$?}; \node (d) at (2,1) {Yes!}; \node (g) at (6,1) {Yes!}; \draw[->] (a) -- (d); \draw[->] (b) -- (g); \draw[->] (l2) -- (a); \draw[->] (l3) -- (b);

        \foreach \x/\n in {.75/1, 3.25/3, 4.75/5, 7.25/7} { \node (\n) at (\x, 1) {$x=\n$}; \node[q] (q) at (\x,0) {$x=\n$?}; \draw[->] (\n) -- (q); \node (y) at (\x,-1) {Yes!}; \draw[->] (q) -- (y); }

        \draw (a) -- (.75, 2.5); \draw[->] (.75, 2.5) -- node[l] {$x<2$} (1); \draw (a) -- (3.25, 2.5); \draw[->] (3.25, 2.5) -- node[l] {$x>2$} (3); \draw (b) -- (4.75, 2.5); \draw[->] (4.75, 2.5) -- node[l] {$x<6$} (5); \draw (b) -- (7.25, 2.5); \draw[->] (7.25, 2.5) -- node[l] {$x>6$} (7);


        \end{scope}
    \end{mypic} \caption{Guessing an~integer $1 \le x \le 7$ by asking at most three questions.} \label{fig:protocol74}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And compiling with pdflatex:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape image0.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To me (apart from the font, which I don't have) the result of your code looks very much like the example you give. Couldn't you just scale the picture on your website (using CSS etc.) to make the font a similar size to the other text? I feel that you need to make a trade-off here between the picture being as similar as possible to that in the book and the font being as small as possible to match the size of the font of your website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems to me that I will not be able to do this with all the pictures. I have a lot of different pictures, about 100, and most likely the standalone scales the text differently in all of them. For example, if the picture itself occupied a whole A4 sheet, then after usage of the standalone, the text on it will be the same as before. If the picture occupied 1/10 of the A4 page, then the text on it will become very large after the standolone. I would like to know how to scale it all to one size.